# Running Spring JUnit tests without @InjectMocks

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, junit, mockito

I am trying to test a class (and it’s methods) using a JUnit test without the @InjectMocks annotation. The annotation will not work for me because the class I am attempting to test has class attributes that @InjectMocks will not create.

Here is what my functional class looks like:
(File path: src/main/java/com/mycompany/mypackage)

```
package com.mycompany.mypackage;

@Service
public class MyClass {

  @Value(“${someString}”)
  private String someString;

  public printString() {
    System.out.println(someString);
  }
}
```

Here is what my testing class looks like:
(File path: src/test/java/com/mycompany/mypackage)

```
package com.mycompany.mypackage;

@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
public class MyClassTest {

  @InjectMocks
  MyClass myClass

  @Test
  public testPrintString() {
    myClass.printString()
  }
}
```

I’ve tried to use @Autowired in the place of @InjectMocks to fully instantiate the MyClass bean, but this will not actually create a instance of MyClass, and I will get a null pointer exception whenever I try to use the ‘myClass’ variable in a test.

For my particular use case, using a constructor method is not a realistic alternative.

Any help would be awesome!

Comment: Fix your `@Service` to use constructor parameters instead of field injection, then you can just say `new MyClass(randomString)`.

Comment: I can’t use a constructor method in my case

Answer (score 1):

If you do not want mock test, you should do as below.

```
// @RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest(classes = YourApplication.class) // YourApplication is your spring boot app main class used to import spring context
public class MyClassTest {

//    @InjectMocks
    @Autowired
    MyClass myClass;

    @Test
    public void testPrintString() {
        myClass.printString();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this to your test class to set the value using reflection:

```
import org.junit.Before;
import org.springframework.test.util.ReflectionTestUtils;

@Before
public void setup()
{
    ReflectionTestUtils.setField(
            myClass,"someString", 
            "SOME_VALUE", String.class);
}
```